# "document.querySelector("").click" not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, click

So I would like to change sensibility of my game when key 1, 2, 3 are pressed. However the last code block is not working (submitSensibilty.click)

```js
 let rangeField = document.querySelector("#sensibilty")
  let submitSensibilty = document.querySelector("#validateSens")


    let sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 8) //Original value
    function validateSens() {
     clearInterval(sensibilty)
     let changeSensibilty = parseFloat(rangeField.value)
     switch (changeSensibilty) {
     case 1: sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 13); break //CHANGING IT WHEN RANGE VALUE = 1
     case 2: sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 8); break //CHANGING IT WHEN RANGE VALUE = 2
     case 3: sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 5); break //CHANGING IT WHEN RANGE VALUE = 3
     default: alert("Sorry, a bug occured")}}
    
     document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 49) {rangeField.value = 1; submitSensibilty.click} //DOES NOT WORK
     if (e.keyCode == 50) {rangeField.value = 2; submitSensibilty.click} //DOES NOT WORK
     if (e.keyCode == 51) {rangeField.value = 3; submitSensibilty.click}}) //DOES NOT WORK
```

```html
<button id="validateSens" onclick="validateSens()"> Submit </button>
    <input type="range" id="sensibilty" min="1" max="3" value="2">
```

Thanks

Comment: Call the function `submitSensibilty.click()`

Comment: Okay here is it https://stackoverflow.com/a/63505722/14097137

Comment: querySelector() get lot of elements which can click by a  loop is needed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I made a stupid mistake. Instead of writing click() I wrote click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function click with `()`

Here's the code "fixed"

```
let rangeField = document.querySelector("#sensibilty")
let submitSensibilty = document.querySelector("#validateSens")


let sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 8) //Original value
function validateSens() {
 clearInterval(sensibilty)
 let changeSensibilty = parseFloat(rangeField.value)
 switch (changeSensibilty) {
 case 1: sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 13); break //CHANGING IT WHEN RANGE VALUE = 1
 case 2: sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 8); break //CHANGING IT WHEN RANGE VALUE = 2
 case 3: sensibilty = setInterval(loop, 5); break //CHANGING IT WHEN RANGE VALUE = 3
 default: alert("Sorry, a bug occured")}}

 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 49) {rangeField.value = 1; submitSensibilty.click()} 
 if (e.keyCode == 50) {rangeField.value = 2; submitSensibilty.click()}
 if (e.keyCode == 51) {rangeField.value = 3; submitSensibilty.click()}})
```